# Can i save an image to the native Photos directory on an Ipad?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

I've got my camera saving images fine to the app path, but my client wants to be able to access the photos from the photos directory (the path that images appear in when you use the native camera apps on the ipad)... I seem to get a "File I/O Error" if i try to save to the "///var/mobile/Media/Photos/" directory, which seems to be the location... is it possible? or is there no security or something involved with that?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but you want to use the [CameraRoll](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html) class. It should do what you want, and seems straight forward to use based on it's simple/short API.

Here's an [Adobe cookbook example](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Use_CameraUI_to_save_image_to_CameraRoll_on_iOS-19113.html) that uses the CameraUI class as well.